How to properly stream to a JSON
I have an app that stores photos locally, and I'm trying to create a way for users to send their photo library to another device.
I created a LibraryTransferPackage struct which can be successfully encoded to/decoded from JSON. This works well for small libraries but for large ones, it uses too much memory trying to hold the file at once and crashes.
I learned about JSON streaming, which seems like a good solution, but I'm having trouble. First it kept crashing because I couldn't figure out the estimated file size. Then I landed on a way to do that using FileHandle, and it successfully creates an output file, but it seems corrupted ("the data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format" when I try to import and decode).
Can anyone help troubleshoot my streaming code, or if not suggest another way to do this?
struct URLDataPair: Codable {

    var url: URL
    var data: Data

}

struct LibraryTransferPackage: Codable {

    var assets: [URLDataPair]

}


let package = LibraryTransferPackage(assets: libraryFiles)


guard let outputFile = OutputStream(url: destinationURL, append: false) else {
        print("^^Failed to open output file")
        return
    }


outputFile.open()

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

do {
    for filePath in libraryFiles.map({$0.url.path}) {
        // Open the files referenced by filePaths
        let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: filePath)
        guard let fileHandle = fileHandle else {
            print("Failed to open file:", filePath)
            continue
        }
        
        defer {
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        
        // Get the size of the file
        let fileSize = fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: 0)
        
        var offset: UInt64 = 0
        let chunkSize = 1024
        
        // Encode the file data into JSON incrementally
        while offset < fileSize {
            let remainingBytes = fileSize - offset
            let bytesToRead = min(UInt64(chunkSize), remainingBytes)
            
            let chunkData = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: Int(bytesToRead))
            
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(chunkData)
            
            let bytesWritten = jsonData.withUnsafeBytes { bufferPointer in
                return outputFile.write(bufferPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, maxLength: jsonData.count)
            }
            
            if bytesWritten < 0 {
                print("Error writing JSON data to output file")
                break
            }
            
            offset += UInt64(bytesToRead)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error encoding JSON data:", error)
}


outputFile.close()


Are you reading image files of type Data that you then encode to Data??? Why involve json at all for this?

@JoakimDanielson I need to package them all in one file, including the file system URLs of where they go. Is there a way to do that without making them a JSON?

Maybe merge and compress

@JoakimDanielson Interesting… do you know how I would go about “unmerging” the file?

@Rob this is all local, sorry if I gave the impression otherwise. I just want it to be one file so it’s easier for the user to transfer to their other device

Re combining files, perhaps the Compression framework, a la Compressing and Decompressing Files with Stream Compression.

@Rob the documentation you link to seems to be expecting a local URL, but I need to compress my custom struct that I haven't written to disk yet. Is it still possible to use Compression for that?

Or perhaps the better question, if my files start as local disk files, can I use stream compression to concatenate them rather than creating a struct to house them and then trying to compress that?
